# Google place api does not search gym in usa

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-places-api, google-places

Google Place api :
I am using the google place api for searching the nearest gym around the user location.But when i using the London latitude and longitude it shows the results accurately but does not show the result for u.s.a. it does not show the results.I don't know what is going here.I am using the https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=19.4333,99.1333&radius=10000&types=gym&sensor=true&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Comment: Give a sample latitude and longitude that you are attempting to use for USA.

Comment: Hey Elizion I am using Newyork latitude and longitude i.e 40.7127° N, 74.0059° W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure you are inputting your latitude/longitude in ***Decimal*** format in order to work properly. 
So for your sample for instance, try replacing `40.7127° N, 74.0059° W` with `40.7127, -74.0059`. See if that helps. 
Most likely London worked for you because both values happened to be positive in decimal format, whereas in the US that evidently isn't the case.

Comment: sorry i am putting the latitude and longitude in decimal format i.e 40.7127, 74.0059

Comment: @UtkarshTiwari Did you place the negative symbol on your second value?

Comment: Ya I am not using negative values.

Comment: No ***USE*** the negative value as I wrote in my replacement. That is part of Decimal format.

Comment: No worries, welcome to SO. Make sure you close your question by selecting the check mark beside my answer if you find my answer sufficient :)